# backup lights stay on in park and switch off

Tags: electrical, ford, lights, explorer

I am working on a 2003 ford explorer sport trac.The backup lights stay on and I have to remove the fuse to turn them off.

Comment: We need to know what kind of transmission it has. The usual failure is a switch but the systems vary greatly between the manual and automatic transmission models.

Comment: Most likely the reverse light switch.

Comment: If the lights stay on even when the key is off something is back feeding into the circuit.

Comment: The transmission is automatic.we have already ruled out the reverse light switch.we also have checked all wiring circuits for continuity.all checked good.but we do have a draw on the battery

Comment: If the lights stay on after power off, I would strongly suspect the harness or wiring, a faulty switch should not keep the light on after the key is removed. A wiring fault on a relay line could keep it closed after the key is removed. Check for cross continuity where there shouldn't be (resistance between 12V and Relay and switch lines). Verify if the relay is actually closed or if the light is feeding from something locally

Comment: @Ben  Is there an answer in your comment regarding the possibility of backfeeding and a simple way to test for that issue?

Comment: @DucatiKiller Well a simple way to test would be to unplug the range switch with the key off. If the lights go out it's the switch or connector. If they stay on you'd have to trace back the wiring to the switch. It looks like the anti-theft system and the autolamp sensor could short and provide power on the circuit. So you could unplug both the antitheft module and the autolamp sensor to verify short to power on the circuit. After that if the lights are still on you'd have to inspect the harness for rub through or whatever.

Comment: @DucatiKiller  But given the comments he made about pulling the fuse it's either the range switch or connector.

Comment: All that sounds like a good answer and your could practically copy/paste what you've said into one.   Then we'll have one less unanswered question on the site.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

> The backup lights stay on and I have to remove the fuse to turn them
>   off.

If the headlamps stay on as well, the daytime running lamp circuit is back feeding into the backup lamp circuit.

But since nothing about the headlamps is mentioned, that can be ruled out.

---

**Step 1**

A simple way to test would be to unplug the range switch with the key off.

**Do the lights go out?**

Inspect the connector and repair as necessary or replace the range switch.

**Do the lights stay on?**

Goto step 2.

---

**Step 2**

The anti-theft module and auto lamp sensor splice into the circuit.

Unplug both the anti-theft module and the auto lamp sensor.

**Do the lights go out?**

Inspect the connector and repair as necessary or replace the module/sensor

**Do the lights stay on?**

Inspect the harness between the range switch and the bulbs for short to power.